# convert bitonal TIFF to bitonal PNG in C#

Tags: c#, jpeg, tiff

I need to convert bitonal (black and white) TIFF files into another format for display by a web browser, currently we're using JPGs, but the format isn't crucial. From reading around .NET doesn't seem to easily support writing bitonal images, so we're ending up with ~1MB files instead of ~100K ones. I'm considering using ImageMagick to do this, but ideally i'd like a solution which doesn't require this if possible.

Current code snippet (which also does some resizing on the image):

```
using (Image img = Image.FromFile(imageName))
{
    using (Bitmap resized = new Bitmap(resizedWidth, resizedHeight)
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(resized))
        {
            g.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, resized.Width, resized.Height), 0, 0, img.Width, img.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }

        resized.Save(outputFilename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the problem can be solved by checking that `resized` bitmap is of `PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed`. If it's not, you should convert it to 1bpp bitmap and after that you can save it as black and white png without problems.

In other words, you should use following code instead of `resized.Save(outputFilename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);`

```
if (resized.PixelFormat != PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed)
{
    using (Bitmap bmp = convertToBitonal(resized))
        bmp.Save(outputFilename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
}
else
{
    resized.Save(outputFilename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

I use following code for `convertToBitonal` :

```
private static Bitmap convertToBitonal(Bitmap original)
{
    int sourceStride;
    byte[] sourceBuffer = extractBytes(original, out sourceStride);

    // Create destination bitmap
    Bitmap destination = new Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height,
        PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);

    destination.SetResolution(original.HorizontalResolution, original.VerticalResolution);

    // Lock destination bitmap in memory
    BitmapData destinationData = destination.LockBits(
        new Rectangle(0, 0, destination.Width, destination.Height),
        ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);

    // Create buffer for destination bitmap bits
    int imageSize = destinationData.Stride * destinationData.Height;
    byte[] destinationBuffer = new byte[imageSize];

    int sourceIndex = 0;
    int destinationIndex = 0;
    int pixelTotal = 0;
    byte destinationValue = 0;
    int pixelValue = 128;
    int height = destination.Height;
    int width = destination.Width;
    int threshold = 500;

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        sourceIndex = y * sourceStride;
        destinationIndex = y * destinationData.Stride;
        destinationValue = 0;
        pixelValue = 128;

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            // Compute pixel brightness (i.e. total of Red, Green, and Blue values)
            pixelTotal = sourceBuffer[sourceIndex + 1] + sourceBuffer[sourceIndex + 2] +
                sourceBuffer[sourceIndex + 3];

            if (pixelTotal > threshold)
                destinationValue += (byte)pixelValue;

            if (pixelValue == 1)
            {
                destinationBuffer[destinationIndex] = destinationValue;
                destinationIndex++;
                destinationValue = 0;
                pixelValue = 128;
            }
            else
            {
                pixelValue >>= 1;
            }

            sourceIndex += 4;
        }

        if (pixelValue != 128)
            destinationBuffer[destinationIndex] = destinationValue;
    }

    Marshal.Copy(destinationBuffer, 0, destinationData.Scan0, imageSize);
    destination.UnlockBits(destinationData);
    return destination;
}

private static byte[] extractBytes(Bitmap original, out int stride)
{
    Bitmap source = null;

    try
    {
        // If original bitmap is not already in 32 BPP, ARGB format, then convert
        if (original.PixelFormat != PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
        {
            source = new Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            source.SetResolution(original.HorizontalResolution, original.VerticalResolution);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(source))
            {
                g.DrawImageUnscaled(original, 0, 0);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            source = original;
        }

        // Lock source bitmap in memory
        BitmapData sourceData = source.LockBits(
            new Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height),
            ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        // Copy image data to binary array
        int imageSize = sourceData.Stride * sourceData.Height;
        byte[] sourceBuffer = new byte[imageSize];
        Marshal.Copy(sourceData.Scan0, sourceBuffer, 0, imageSize);

        // Unlock source bitmap
        source.UnlockBits(sourceData);

        stride = sourceData.Stride;
        return sourceBuffer;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (source != original)
            source.Dispose();
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried saving using the [Image.Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ytz20d80.aspx) overload with [Encoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64h235xe.aspx) parameters?
Like the [Encoder.ColorDepth Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.encoder.colordepth.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

Trying jaroslav's suggestion for color depth doesn't work:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        var list = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();
        var jpegEncoder = list[1]; // i know this is the jpeg encoder by inspection
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(500, 500);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
        g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red), 10, 10, 300, 300);
        var encoderParams = new EncoderParameters();
        encoderParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.ColorDepth, 2);
        bitmap.Save(@"c:\newbitmap.jpeg", jpegEncoder, encoderParams);

}
```

The jpeg is still a full color jpeg.

I don't think there is any support for grayscale jpeg in gdi plus. Have you tried looking in windows imaging component?

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8e011506-6307-445b-b950-215def45ddd8&displaylang=en

code example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/windows_imaging.aspx

wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Imaging_Component

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Have you tried PNG with 1 bit color depth?</strike>

To achieve a size similar to a CCITT4 TIFF, I believe your image needs to use a 1-bit indexed pallette.

However, you can't use the Graphics object in .NET to draw on an indexed image.

You will probably have to use LockBits to manipulate each pixel.

See [Bob Powell's excellent article](https://web.archive.org/web/20140906075741/http://bobpowell.net/onebit.aspxhttp://www.bobpowell.net/onebit.htm).

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread.  However, I'll add my 2 cents.

I use AForge.Net libraries (open source)

use these dlls.  `Aforge.dll`, `AForge.Imaging.dll`

```
using AForge.Imaging.Filters;

private void ConvertBitmap()
{
    markedBitmap = Grayscale.CommonAlgorithms.RMY.Apply(markedBitmap);
    ApplyFilter(new FloydSteinbergDithering());
}
private void ApplyFilter(IFilter filter)
{
    // apply filter
    convertedBitmap = filter.Apply(markedBitmap);
}
```