# Convert TIFF LZW to CCITT

Tags: c#, compression, tiff

This is a question about TIFF and compression. I have hundreds of LZW compressed tiff images. I wonder, is it possible to convert those to CCITT T.6? Is there some API? Please help.

Comment: Are you looking for a command line tool or something that you can call in code? What operating system?

Comment: I am looking for any solution. OS: Windows Server 2008 and Win 7.

Answer (score 3):

LZW compression can be used to compress almost any image. CCITT T.6 can compress only bilevel (black and white) images.

If your images are bilevel ones and they are compressed with LZW compression then you can recompress them using tiffcp utility (comes with [LibTiff.Net](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/) library, free, source code available).

If your images are full-color ones then you will have to convert them to bilevel first. One of my answers contains [sample code for such conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3415886/249690).