# Tiff file compression with C#

Tags: c#, tiff

I have a tiff file which during original creation and saving has compression type "LZW".

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(800, 1000); 
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
fileName = saveDirectory + id + ".tif";
bitmap.Save(fileName, ImageFormat.Tiff);
```

So I am trying to change its compression to CCIT:-

```
Bitmap myBitmap;
myBitmap = new Bitmap(fileName);
ImageCodecInfo myImageCodecInfo;
myImageCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo("image/tiff");
System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder;
myEncoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Compression;
EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters;
myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter;      
myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder,(long)EncoderValue.CompressionCCITT4);
myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
myBitmap.Save(new_fileName);

    private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(String mimeType)
    {
      int j;
      ImageCodecInfo[] encoders;
      encoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
      for (j = 0; j < encoders.Length; ++j)
        {
            if (encoders[j].MimeType == mimeType)
            return encoders[j];
        }
      return null;
    }
```

However, after running through the process, my file properties still says that it is of the "LZW compression" type.

Can anyone explain to me where I am going wrong with this?

Comment: Check out the response to this question [Convert TIFF LZW to CCITT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319508/convert-tiff-lzw-to-ccitt)

Comment: Not an explanation to my original question. But thank you for the link.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change your last line to:

```
myBitmap.Save(new_fileName, myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters);
```

Comment: ah snap. totally overlooked applying the encoding ... thanks man!

Comment: one more question. what if i wanted to delete the old file and save the new file with the old filename

Comment: There're several ways to accomplish that. I'd probably create a new `Bitmap` and copy my image using the `Graphics` to it so I can close the reference to the original (which holds it open.) Do that and you can just `Save()` over it.

Comment: also, my whole tiff file now comes off as a black image. There should be writing and stuff on it.... haha any idea???

Comment: The image has visible features and works with all other compression types, except for the type I need - CCITT...with CCITT compression the image produced is all black. as if a layer.

Comment: There's a TIFF tag that affects the background color (photometric I think?), that's probably it but I don't have time now to look into it.

Comment: Hey Nick,

I have added a new question with the issue I am having.. can you please help ?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192691/c-after-applying-ccitt-compression-on-my-tiff-file-it-produces-an-image-with