# Having issue converting 32 bit images to bitonal black and white

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, image-processing, imaging

I have the following code routine...

```
Public Shared Sub ConvertToBitonal(ByRef Source As System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap)
    If Source.Format = System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.BlackWhite Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim BytesPerPixel As Integer = (Source.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8
    Dim Stride As Integer = Source.PixelWidth * BytesPerPixel
    Dim NumBytes As Long = Source.PixelHeight * Stride
    Dim pixels As Byte() = New Byte(NumBytes - 1) {}

    Source.CopyPixels(pixels, Stride, 0)

    For cnt As Integer = 0 To pixels.Length - 1 Step BytesPerPixel
        Dim blue As Byte = pixels(cnt + 0)
        Dim green As Byte = pixels(cnt + 1)
        Dim red As Byte = pixels(cnt + 2)
        Dim intensity As Integer = CType(red, Integer) + CType(green, Integer) + CType(blue, Integer)
        Dim targetColor As Byte

        If intensity > 400 Then
            targetColor = 255
        Else
            targetColor = 0
        End If

        pixels(cnt + 0) = targetColor
        pixels(cnt + 1) = targetColor
        pixels(cnt + 2) = targetColor
        pixels(cnt + 3) = targetColor
    Next

    Source.WritePixels(New System.Windows.Int32Rect(0, 0, Source.PixelWidth, Source.PixelHeight), pixels, Stride, 0)
End Sub
```

When the source image is of the 24 bit per pixel variety the output comes out exactly how I want it, but when the source image is 32 bits the colors do not come out solid and I get vertical lines running throughout the image. Can someone show me how to modify the routine so that the 32 bit images come out like their 24 bit counter parts?

Here is a screen shot of what I'm talking about... (Apparently I don't have enough rep yet to post images so here is a link instead

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to create a 24bpp copy of the image first.  Have you tried that?

I did something similar long ago (too long ago to recall details), this article was helpful: [Bitonal conversion issues](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15186/Bitonal-TIFF-Image-Converter-for-NET).  There was also some info on MSDN forum.

EDIT: [seen this entry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414072/convert-bitonal-tiff-to-bitonal-png-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Re: Posted URLs... Yes I am familiar with those 2 articles. This code that I am posting about is from a document imaging system viewer that I originally wrote in GDI+. The posts you detailed are also referring to the GDI way of doing things. However, as storage has become cheaper and cameras have increased in megapixels our imaging system (and GDI+) has run into limitations with the size of images it can handle... which leads me to now... I'm currently rewriting the system for WPF which can handle much larger images.

Comment: Re: Creating a 24 bbp copy first. This was my first thought too... the problem for me with this approach though is that when I use a FormatConvertedBitmap to change the image some funky stuff happens with the caching which causes the image to sometimes turn to a 1x1 pixel image (even though the image is much larger).

Comment: Answer: In case anyone comes across this what I had to do to get this working is in fact convert to 24 bits per pixel. The reason the image was turning to 1x1 pixels was that I was running out of memory in my save routine which saves within a loop from pages 1 to N. It seems the trick to working with WPF bitmap sources and their derived classes is that you cannot scope variables within blocks of code and expect garbage collection to pick them up - even if you explicitly call garbage collection.

Comment: Continued: Instead, declare variables that are scoped for your entire routine (in my case outside of the loop) and reuse them. Reusing the same variables over and over is the only way I can seem to get the memory to release.

Answer (score 0):

I dug around the code and see the problem:

```
Dim BytesPerPixel As Integer = (Source.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8
```

Remove the `+ 7`.

Also change this:

```
    pixels(cnt + 0) = targetColor

    pixels(cnt + 1) = targetColor

    pixels(cnt + 2) = targetColor

    pixels(cnt + 3) = targetColor
```

to a FOR loop encompassing the step..... i.e.:

```
        Dim x%

        For x = cnt To cnt + BytesPerPixel - 1

            pixels(x) = targetColor

        Next
```

If the step is > 4, it's not going to set the value and will give you this bar going down it.

Comment: The `BytesPerPixel` calculation is derived from the full formula where the bpp is multiplied by the image width, then done +7 and then divided by 8. This is necessary for images with a bpp lower than 8, to round the partially used data up to the next full byte. But without involving the width, the code seems rather useless, since it'd assume that the pixel width of a 4bpp image is 1, which is incorrect if that value is then used for calculating the actual byte width.

Comment: That said, for images with a bpp perfectly divisible by 8 (as most >=8bpp are) the `+7` will have no influence at all, since int always rounds down, so there's no need to remove it either. And your other edit is also just a code optimisation (which doesn't even optimise the program efficiency), not a fix...